# Can I use environment variables or tilde in module.modulemap?

Tags: swift, module, environment-variables, tilde-expansion, module-map

My `module.modulemap` file looks like this:

```swift
module CompanyInternalSDK {
    header "~/Company/CompanyInternalSDK.framework/Headers/CompanyInternalSDK.h"
    export *
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
/Users/username/Path/To/Project/CompanyInternalSDK/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '~/Company/CompanyInternalSDK.framework/Headers/CompanyInternalSDK.h' not found
    header "~/Company/CompanyInternalSDK.framework/Headers/CompanyInternalSDK.h"
           ^
```

It compiles just fine when I use the absolute path without the tilde, but since this will be distributed like this to all developers, I want to use the tilde. **Is there any way to make this work correctly?**

---

I also tried to use an environment variable in the `header` string, but that didn't work either:

```swift
module CompanyInternalSDK {
    header "${HOME}/Company/CompanyInternalSDK.framework/Headers/CompanyInternalSDK.h"
    export *
}
```

```
/Users/username/Path/To/Project/CompanyInternalSDK/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '${HOME}/Company/CompanyInternalSDK.framework/Headers/CompanyInternalSDK.h' not found
    header "${HOME}/Company/CompanyInternalSDK.framework/Headers/CompanyInternalSDK.h"
           ^
```

Comment: Instead of using the Tilde, which is a shell expansion character, try using the environment variable ${HOME}. Though I'm not sure even environment variable expansion will be applied at compile time.

Comment: @ScottThompson I tried that, and it didn't work

Comment: Ben, are you tried just `header "CompanyInternalSDK.h"` in your modulemap file?

Comment: @MaxPotapov yes, same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the modulemap syntax does not expand tildes or environment variables. It ultimately just expects to `stat` the path you gave it, and if no file's there, it'll gripe.

- [Here's](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a8947ba0ec07fa1d0928652b940938064afbb4e0/lib/Lex/ModuleMap.cpp#L1888) where the header file lookup is kicked off, during lexing of the module map file.
- It ultimately passes the path to the SourceManager's FileManager to produce a `File` object, as [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a8947ba0ec07fa1d0928652b940938064afbb4e0/lib/Lex/ModuleMap.cpp#L1907) for a header in a framework's `Headers/` public header folder.
- [`getFile`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a8947ba0ec07fa1d0928652b940938064afbb4e0/lib/Basic/FileManager.cpp#L215) ultimately ends up calling out to [`getStatValue`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a8947ba0ec07fa1d0928652b940938064afbb4e0/lib/Basic/FileManager.cpp#L462-L468), which does a cache lookup.
- The [`FileSystemStatCache::get`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/a8947ba0ec07fa1d0928652b940938064afbb4e0/lib/Basic/FileSystemStatCache.cpp#L34-L45) eventually grounds out in LLVM's filesystem abstraction, where it calls [`sys::fs::status`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/3f8d08861b7ddd4eed675fcde19eb1d5fe38496f/include/llvm/Support/FileSystem.h#L613-L622), which is documented to act like POSIX `stat`.
- POSIX `stat` works with paths as-is, no tilde or environment variable expansion - the common availability of those is due to the shell helping you out, not something that happens automatically most of the time at the system level.

However, it's standard to **use relative paths** in module maps. The lexer respects this, and all the module map docs demonstrate this. In the common case where your module map file is colocated with your library and installed alongside it, this should suffice to properly resolve the paths.